# How to Add a Third Table in an SQL Query Containing a SUM

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT porel.refcode, podetail.ponum, SUM(podetail.orderqty * podetail.unitcost) AS Total
FROM podetail
LEFT JOIN porel ON podetail.ponum = porel.ponum
WHERE porel.poline=podetail.poline AND porel.reftype = 'SPEX'
GROUP BY porel.refcode, podetail.ponum
ORDER BY porel.refcode, podetail.ponum
```

which works fine to bring me a list of `ponums` and their total values against `refcodes`.

I now want to add a third column `vendor.name`.  The `vendor` table has a field `vendorid` which it shares with the `podetail` table.

There are multiple `podetail` records with the same `ponum` but these will also have matching `vendorid`'s.

Could someone advise how I would add in the `vendor.name` field without returning extra rows?

Comment: Can you add the structure of the table(s), sample data for the rows, expected output etc in form of screenshot or textual mode?

Comment: @shahkalpesh - I'm not at work now so can't do it right now but will post that first thing on Monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heya, Rogue.  I wanted to say a little more than fits in a comment, so here.

One more easy diagnostic off the top of my head is this:

```
SELECT
    porel.refcode,
    podetail.ponum,
    SUM(podetail.orderqty * podetail.unitcost) AS Total,
    podetail.vendorid
FROM
    podetail
    LEFT JOIN porel
    ON podetail.ponum = porel.ponum
WHERE
    porel.poline = podetail.poline 
    AND porel.reftype = 'SPEX' 
GROUP BY
    porel.refcode, 
    podetail.ponum,
    podetail.vendorid
ORDER BY
    refcode, 
    ponum
```

In here, we don't join to `vendor` at all, taking the table completely out of the equation.  Instead, we'll just roll up `podetail.vendorid`s instead.

Can you post the output of this query?

Comment: Please, please, shoot me now!  I ran the query as you suggested and was checking the results by running `SELECT * from vendor WHERE vendorid = *etc*` when I noticed that there *are* multiple vendors with the same vendorid! The vendor table has entries for multiple departments (companies) and different departments can have the same `vendornum` but for different vendors.  What a schoolboy mistake :-s I've now added a `AND podetail.company = vendor.company` to the `WHERE` clause and it's working a treat.  Thank you for all your help and sorry to have wasted your time

Comment: @Rogue - Awesome. One more thing: You'd asked a couple times about a nested `SELECT ... WHERE EXISTS ... SELECT`. When people get more rows than you expect from a `JOIN`, they aren't sure why it's like that exactly, but they're tempted to throw some "fix it" syntax at it like `DISTINCT`, `TOP`, `MAX`, `WHERE IN ...` etc. Sometimes it's fine but it very often means there's something wrong underneath and you're masking over it.  Just keep that in mind when you encounter this situation again.  Anyway, enough preaching - good luck with the rest of your queries. :)

Comment: Many thanks, I'll definitely bear that in mind for the future.  I come from more of a programming background than a DB one so although I'm picking up the SQL syntax pretty quickly I'm still stumbling over some of the intricacies of database design; so your help and sanity checks have been invaluable.

Answer (score 2):

Add it into the `GROUP BY`. I have assumed that there will be one vendor for each `podetail.ponum`. By the way your current query is converting the left join to an inner join because of the `porel.reftype = 'SPEX'` in the Where clause.

```
SELECT   porel.refcode,
         podetail.ponum,
         SUM(podetail.orderqty * podetail.unitcost) AS Total,
         vendor.name
FROM     podetail
         INNER JOIN vendor ON podetail.vendorid = vendor.vendorid
         LEFT JOIN porel ON podetail.ponum = porel.ponum
WHERE    porel.poline=podetail.poline
AND      porel.reftype = 'SPEX'
GROUP BY porel.refcode,
         podetail.ponum,
         vendor.name
ORDER BY porel.refcode,
         podetail.ponum
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Martin, I'm new to SQL so that's a big help.  Your solution almost works but it is returning multiple identical ponums, all with the same Total but with different vendor names.

I think my initial question might not have been specific enough so, to clarify; there are multiple podetail records with the same ponum (these are lines on a purchase order) but I need the total for the purchase order as a whole so I somehow need to work out orderqty * unitcost for each podetail record, then add these totals together for records with the same ponum.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Rogue - But if there are multiple vendor names which one do you want to return in your query then?

Comment: There is only one vendor name associated with each podetail record (via the vendorid field).  Where there are multiple podetail records with the same ponum they all have the same vendorid.

Comment: For example, there may be two podetail records with a ponum of '12345' (two lines on purchase order 12345) but they will both have identical vendorids.

Comment: Before adding the vendor data into the mix, the query in my initial question only returned one line for each ponum.  Adding the vendor table has resulted in the same ponum being returned multiple times.

Comment: Did you include `vendor.name` in the `group by`? Most RDBMSs would insist on this but I think if you are using MySQL it might not.

Comment: Thanks for persevering. I've just tried that but all it seems to do is remove the `ponum` column from the results, which I need.  The lines are still being duplicated.

It looks like the join to the `vendor` table is incorrect and returning multiple matches instead of just one.

Comment: I've just checked and, yes, `vendor.name` is in the `group by`.

Comment: I have seen another query which used a nested `SELECT` with `WHERE EXISTS` but am not familiar with the construction of such a query.  Could that be a solution?

Comment: @Rogue - I think you need to validate your assumption that "Where there are multiple podetail records with the same ponum they all have the same vendorid."

Comment: @Rogue - I have the same suspicion as Martin Smith.  Would you try something like `select ponum, count(distinct vendorid) as numvendors from podetail group by ponum` and see if numvendors is ever > 1?

Comment: @Martin - That's definitely the case.  For example, the query is returning lines similar to the following:

Refcode  |  poline  |  ponum  |  total  |  name
10000    |     1    |  12345  |  20000  | ABC Systems
10000    |     1    |  12345  |  20000  | DEF Ltd

but ponum 12345 has only one line with a value of 20000.

Comment: @Matt - I ran the query you suggested and `numvendors` is exactly 1 for all 13000+ rows.

Comment: @Rogue - Thanks, I'm convinced!  And, just to make sure as a sanity check, vendorid is definitely, definitely unique in the vendor table?  Sorry to ask these dumb questions - remote debugging is hard.

Comment: @Matt - I know what you mean, remote explaining isn't easy either :-)  Yes, `vendorid` is **definitely** unique in the `vendor` table.  I've uploaded a file to http://drop.io/sqloq4h which shows a better example of the output I'm getting.  And, to be clear, ponum 12345 in that example was only showing up once until I added the vendor link.

Comment: @Rogue - OK, now I see why this is frustrating. Because, by your DB structure, one PO must only have one vendorId must only have one name. Maybe I'll have some other ideas after lunch but this is the only other option I got for now - maybe PO is a string with trailing whitespace, and `group by` was inappropriately collapsing both `'12345'` and `'12345 '` before? In the following SO question, Martin discovered that `distinct` was doing that. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493705/why-does-select-distinct-a-b-from-return-fewer-records-than-select-distinc)

Comment: @Matt - Yes, you're right, `ponum` and `vendorid` are set by a table further up the structure, namely `poheader`.  `poheader` is the top level purchase order table and the `podetail` records are individual lines on the purchase orders.  So, there will be only one `poheader` record with a `ponum` of 12345 but there may be multiple lines on the order and therefore multiple `podetail` records with a `ponum` of 12345.  The `vendorid` is also set at the `poheader` level and inherited by all the `podetail` records associated with is so they will all have the same `vendorid`.  Does that help?

Comment: I don't think that there will be any whitespace in the `ponum` as the values are auto-generated by a frontend but I'll check when I get back to work on Monday, just to make sure.  Thanks for sticking with me on this one, it's driving me crazy!

Comment: @Matt - I've just checked and there doesn't seem to be any whitespace in the `ponum` values.

Comment: +1, this answer was technically correct and, better, you've called out the conversion of the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`. At best, this kind of confuses the intention of the query.  At worst, it might be a mistake!

Comment: I agree with Matt on that.  As soon as I have sufficient reputation I'll +1 this too.  Thanks for your help Martin.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   porel.refcode,
         podetail.poline,
         podetail.ponum,
         SUM(podetail.orderqty * podetail.unitcost) AS Total,
         vendor.name
FROM     podetail
         INNER JOIN vendor ON podetail.vendorid = vendor.vendorid
         LEFT JOIN porel ON podetail.ponum = porel.ponum
WHERE    porel.poline=podetail.poline
AND      porel.reftype = 'SPEX'
GROUP BY porel.refcode,
         podetail.ponum,
         vendor.name
ORDER BY porel.refcode,
         podetail.poline,
         podetail.ponum
```

I think, you are missing the need to include `podetail.poline` in your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Adding `podetail.poline` as you suggest shows the same `poline` multiple times for each repeated `ponum`.

The more I look at this the more it seems like the join to the `vendor` table is wrong and is therefore returning duplicate lines.

Comment: I have seen another query which used a nested `SELECT` with `WHERE EXISTS` but am not familiar with the construction of such a query.  Could that be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are aggregating podetails, simply aggregate vendor names:

```
SELECT porel.refcode, podetail.ponum
, MAX(vendor.name) as VendorName
, SUM(podetail.orderqty * podetail.unitcost) AS Total
FROM podetail
LEFT JOIN vendor on podetail.vendorid = vendor.vendorid
LEFT JOIN porel ON podetail.ponum = porel.ponum
WHERE porel.poline=podetail.poline AND porel.reftype = 'SPEX'
GROUP BY porel.refcode, podetail.ponum
ORDER BY porel.refcode, podetail.ponum
```

Or use MIN() if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Aggregating the vendor names doesn't seem to work either.  Running your version of the query returns one line for each `ponum` (which is what I want) but the vendor name and values are incorrect.

I could be wrong, but aggregating the vendors seems to be going at it from the wrong direction; especially as without the aggregation the query is returning multiple different vendors for the same po, which is incorrect.  I would imagine that trying to aggregate multiple different vendors will always have a chance of returning the wrong vendor.

Comment: Surely there must be a way to connect the `vendor` table in such a way that it only returns the correct vendor.  Maybe through a nested `SELECT` statement?

Comment: You obviously have not fully described the foreign key reference from podetail to vendor. Once we know what uniquely identifies a podetail, porel and vendor, we will give you answers that return the results you want.